# What’s the NCVA at the end of the F135 engine?

Tags: jet-engine

[image]

What’s NCVA at the end of the F135 engine? And what does it do?

Answer (score 2):

NCVA: Nozzle cooling valve actuator.

It allows a cooling flow to enter the nozzle. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_F135):

> In this configuration most of the bypass flow is ducted to the wing nozzles, known as roll posts. Some is used for cooling the rear exhaust nozzle, known as the 3-bearing swivel duct nozzle (3BSD).[37] At the same time an auxiliary inlet is opened on top of the aircraft to provide additional air to the engine with low distortion during the hover.[31]

[image]

<sup>[Source](https://www.moog.com/content/dam/moog/literature/Aircraft/military_aftermarket/Moog-F35-Brochure.pdf)</sup>

Comment: "Valve" or "vane"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Thanks!! Vanne is a French synonymous for valve...